# Dismiss keyboard when UITextField created programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield

I have created a UITextField programmatically.  I want to dismiss keyboard after entering the text.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[yourfield resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: I have written same code to dismiss keyboard but its not working.Its my code snippet

Comment: UITextField *userNameTextfield=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160,170, 140.0, 18.0)];[userNameTextfield setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES]; [userNameTextfield resignFirstResponder];

Comment: when you want to hide the keyboard..at that place you should have the resignFirstResponder method.. not the place where you initialize it..

Comment: - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
[self textFieldDidEndEditing:userNameTextfield];

Comment: - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
[self textFieldDidEndEditing:userNameTextfield]; I wrote like this still it is not working.I went through apple documents, But still i didn't get any proper clue

Comment: make a new method ..arbitarty name like .. `doThis`..in it put use userNameTextfield resignFirst....  the current method you use is textfield delegate's method..might be problem in that... call `se;f doThis];` whenever you want to dismiss keyboard..also are you sure you have only one text field on screen?

Comment: Yeah I am sure, I have only one text field.I have created uiview my uiview programmatically, then created uitextfield mytextfield , this text field i am adding on  my view.e.g.[mytextfiled addsubview:myuiview],[self.view  addsubview:myuiview],hope it can give some clue to u to understand the problem.thanks for ur prompt reply

Answer (score 2):

Study UITextField Class Reference, its very easy, you just need to spend some time with theory.

Comment: I went through UITextFiled Reference class . all what i get here is [mytextfield resignFirstrespnder];But I am not understanding ,when and     from where [mytextfiled resignFirstResponder] should  call.

Answer (score 2):

If you added the texfield dynamically try this

```
[texfield addTarget:self action:@selector(resignFirstResponder)forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
```